# Gson: JSON deserialization issue

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON file using custom deserialization from Gson but I guess I'm failing to do it, nothing is being deserialized. Here's my code

Please also guide me if I'm using incorrect return type. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly as well.

GsonHelper.java

```
public <T> T ProcessData(Class<T> ClassType, String Data)
{

     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ClassType , new 
     JsonDeserializerHelper(ClassType)).create();
     return gson.fromJson(Data,ClassType);

}
```

JsonDeserializerHelper.java

```
public class JsonDeserializerHelper implements JsonDeserializer {

private Class<?> InstantiatedClass;
private static final Logger logger = 
Logger.getLogger(JsonDeserializerHelper.class.getName());

public JsonDeserializerHelper(Class instantiatedClass) {
    this.InstantiatedClass = instantiatedClass;
}

@Override
public Object deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, 
    JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) json;


        // Implementation here
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Also whenever I try to return a generic type of `T`, I can't .

What I try to achieve is to have a generic function that returns any class based on the instantiated class in it's private class.

The variable that is consuming the functions afterall

```
  Class<?> AnonymousClass = Class.forName(ClassName);
  ProcessClassHelper helperClass = new ProcessClassHelper();
    Object ParsedData = (AccountInfo)helperClass.ProcessData(AnonymousClass,json);

     ArrayList<AccountInfo> test = (ArrayList<AccountInfo>) ParsedData;
     for (AccountInfo acc : test)
      {
          logger.info("First Name: " + acc.getFirstName());
      }
```

Also the last logger outputs nothing.

Comment: I'm assuming you have .NET background. You have to know that `Class<T>` is not the same as .NET `Type` is. You need `java.lang.reflect.Type` that can hold any Java type including generics. Note that Gson has a ready-to-use overload to accept `java.lang.reflect.Type`. `AnyClass.class` is already a `java.lang.reflect.Type` instance. Generics can be instanitated either with specialized factory methods or anonymous implementations, or just Gson `TypeToken`s.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Yes that's correct Lyu, thanks for your comment and sorry for my late reply. Actually I've tried reflecting after posting my comment but yet I'm failing with the deserialization. I can't tell what's causing this.

Also thanks for correcting my question and editing it.

Comment: Just don't use `Class<T>` (it cannot hold generics) and just try to use something like `gson.fromJson(..., new TypeToken<YourAnyTypeHere>(){}.getType());` -- this is more or less an idiomatic way of creating a parameterized type.